# Difference between access="permitAll" and filters="none"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Here is a part from Spring Security petclinic example:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login />
    <logout />
</http>
```

What is the difference between access="permitAll" and filters="none"?

**Url:** http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The difference is that `filters = "none"` disables Spring Security filters for the specified URLs, whereas `access = "permitAll"` configures authorization without disabling filters.

In practice, `filters = "none"` may cause problems when resources behind it require some functionality of Spring Security. For example, you can't use it for user registration page that performs programmatic login on submit ([User Granted Authorities are always : ROLE_ANONYMOUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923296/user-granted-authorities-are-always-role-anonymous)).

Comment: So should I use `access = "permitAll"` instead of `filters = "none"` even for css and js files for a secured application?

Comment: I commented at your link too.

Comment: @kamaci: As far as I understand, `filters = "none"` shoudn't cause any problems for static resources. However, if you use it for dynamic resources, you need to keep the difference in mind.

Comment: So I will use filters="none" for static resources?

Comment: @kamaci: Yes, I think using `filers = "none"` for static resources wouldn't cause any problem.