# Spring authorization without authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am doing SAML based authentication in my application, and able to fetch the user role and id through SAML api, now How can I set this values for Spring role based authorization as my login module is not calling Spring form login,in that case how the AuthenticationManager fetch these values?

Comment: Looks like you don't need authentication manager if you have already got the user details. You can programmatically let Spring Security know that user is authenticated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484139/

Comment: Thanks @Rites h I solved the issue by adding a Pre Auth Filter