# User registration validation through email with Spring Roo

Tags: validation, email, hyperlink, registration, spring-roo

I want to add a feature to my spring roo project. I have an user entity that logs into the application and adds additional users.
When I add those users there is an email adress(field) on which I want to send the validation with additional link to activating the account. Also the user has a field that represents if he or she has an active profile in a way is it possible to log in or not - this field needs to change after I click the provided link in the email.

I already have an velocity templates and everything set up, I just need the process of forming that link and assuring that the user will have an active account after clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using a REST call and Spring Security.  When the user first signs up, you create the [UserDetails](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) object (mine was in a DB table), but set it as not enabled before you save it (there are 4 booleans in the UserDetails object you can manipulate to enable/disable the user in various ways that Spring Security checks).  I also stored a UUID code I generated off the user id in a table, and then generated an email which included a link to the REST service to validate the account.

The REST service was simple.  The user clicks the link, which would include the UUID code I generated.  You could optionally require them to enter some number or do something here as another authentication step, but in my case I simply looked up the UUID to get the associated UserDetails, flipped the bit to enabled and saved it, and sent them to a page saying their account was now active.  I then did something like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813028/auto-login-after-successful-registeration) to auto-login the user.