# Spring security auto login after registeration

Tags: spring-security, autologin

I create a spring MVC application that uses spring security for authentication, here's the spring-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/homepage.jsp" default-target-url="/homepage.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/homepage.jsp?login-success=false" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/homepage.jsp" />
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" > 
   <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="sha" />
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="marketDataSource" 

       users-by-username-query="
          select email_address, password, '1' 
          from user where email_address=?" 

        authorities-by-username-query="
          select email_address, 'ROLE_USER' from user 
          where email_address=?" 
      />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

when a new user try to register, he fill in registration from and press submit, that will create a new user, if the registration successfully completed, I try to authenticate the registered user using this method:

```
private void authenticateUserAndSetSession(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {

List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
    user.getEmailAddress(), user.getPasswordSha(), grantedAuthorities);

request.getSession();

token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
try {
  Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager
      .authenticate(token);
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I checked this post [Auto login after successful registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813028/auto-login-after-successful-registeration) to make the previous method, but when I try to use it, it throws Bad Credential Exception, what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: Are you passing encrypted password to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?

Comment: yes I'm passing encrypted password

Comment: That is the problem. In linked post they use clear password.

Answer (score 0):

I had been faced with the similar problem. In legacy code the password was hashed by hand.

The better choice is to store object of User class (may be it is a plain form binding) with the plain password and clear it later. Clearing credencials is the responsibility of spring-security too (interface `org.springframework.security.core.CredentialsContainer`).
If it isn't possible remove tag of encoder or use the plain text encoder `<password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>`.