# Spring Security 3.2 - Adding Signup Form to Login Page

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have integrated Spring Security login successfuly to my wb application. However, I would like to have in the login page, in addition to login form, a signup form.

In order to do validation I need to pass to that form the object SignupForm which represents my form.

How can I do it? I have tried so many approaches and nothing works.

Please help....

Comment: What does "not work" look like?

Comment: I would like to have validation on tbe signhp form. For tbat I have to pass the form command as an attribute.

Comment: How do I add an attribue to the Model before the login page is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list><value>classpath:com/harryfwong/config/messages</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

## message.properties in com.harryfwong.config resource package

```
username.required=Username is required
password.required=Password is required
passwordconfirm.mustmatch=Password must match
email.required=Email is required
```

## Spring Validator

```
<!-- language: java -->
public class SignUpFormValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return SignUpForm.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "username.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "password.required");

        SignUpForm form = (SignUpForm) target;

        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(form.getPassword())) {
            if (!form.getPassword().equals(form.getPasswordConfirm())) {
                errors.rejectValue("passwordConfirm", "passwordconfirm.mustmatch");
            }            
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "email.required");

    }

}
```

## Controller

```
<!-- language: java -->
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="signup")
    public String signup(@ModelAttribute("form") SignUpForm form) {
        if (form == null) {
            form = new SignUpForm();
        }
        return "auth/signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="signup")
    public String signupSuccess(@ModelAttribute("form") SignUpForm form, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        SignUpFormValidator suValidator = new SignUpFormValidator();
        suValidator.validate(form, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return signup(form);
        } else {
            authenticateUserAndSetSession(form, request);
            return "auth/signupSuccess";
        }
    }
```

External Reference Login after signup: [Auto login after successful registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813028/auto-login-after-successful-registeration)

Comment: Hopefully that helps - that is for the signup portion

Comment: Thanks very much for all, it was very helpful. My mistake was that i forgot to add a method with get to create the Form object before calling the page.

Answer (score 0):

What does your SS configuration currently look like?

```
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        login-processing-url="/loginProcess"
        default-target-url="/landing"
        always-use-default-target="false" />
```

Where /login is the request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="login")
public String login() {
    // do something prior to display form below
    return "auth/login";
}
```

auth/login.jsp

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='/loginProcess' />"
    method='POST'>
```

Comment: I know how to add a login form. Actually I already added a custom login page. My question is how to add a Signup form to my login page. In the past I had a separate Signup page so it was easy to create the model object and to pass it to the Model via the controller. However, now the login page is called automatically and I have no chance to create the Signup object. Is there a filter that I can use to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your security context config looks like - this is a response to your issue about not getting to the signup page

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/loggedout" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

...

</http>
```