# Spring boot: java.lang.StackOverflowError:null when trying to auto-login after successful registration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to auto-login after a successful registration. I followed these [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813028/auto-login-after-successful-registration) and [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-auto-login-user-after-registration) but I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError : null` when testing my code via Postman.

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/api/user/registration")
    public ResponseEntity registerNewUserAccount(
            @RequestBody @Valid RegistrationDto userDto, HttpServletRequest request){

        userService.save(userDto);
        authenticateUser(userDto, request);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    private void authenticateUser(RegistrationDto userDto, HttpServletRequest request){
        String username = userDto.getEmailAddress();
        String password = userDto.getPassword();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        request.getSession();
        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
        Authentication authenticatedUser =
                authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder cryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I know about `StackOverflowError` and I guess `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` or `authenticationManagerBean` should cause the problem.

Here's a piece of the lengthy error message:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:503) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess was right :) You should configure `AuthenticationManager` correctly. The links you refer don't explicitly show that.

There are *many* ways how to configure it: Provide an implementation of `AuthenticationManager` explicitly, or configure a builder that will create an `AuthenticationManager`, or configure `AuthenticationManager` via XML, etc. Below are 2 of *many* possible ways to configure it.

**1. Provide your own AuthenticationManager**

For some *real* authentication you can implement an `AuthenticationManager` that is based on LDAP or JDBC. To demonstrate the idea, here is a *dummy* implementation which is *sufficient* to make your code running.

```
public class DummyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Dummy implementation. We don't check anything here.
        return authentication;
    }

}
```

In your `SecurityConfiguration` create an instance of it, as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return new DummyAuthenticationManager();
    }

    ...

}
```

With these changes your code will be running and you can continue to extend it step by step.

**2. Use AuthenticationManagerBuilder**

Instead of implementing an `AuthenticationManager` you can configure `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` that will *build* for you an `AuthenticationManager` that you need.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("user2").password("password2").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password3").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    ...
}
```

With these changes your code will be running and you can continue to extend it step by step. For instance, for something realistic instead of `inMemoryAuthentication()` you can use `ldapAuthentication()` or `jdbcAuthentication()` or some other configurer.